# Tools for 3D rendering

Tags: hadoop, 3d, rendering, visualization, distributed-computing

It's known that 3D rendering is computation expensive.

And I want to use `Apache Hadoop` for distributed 3D rendering (rendering images or videos)  to reduce rendering time.  So after learning about Hadoop, I understand that I need 2 things:

- Data, which will be visualized (probably it some kind of file, which contains instructions (like draw rectangle, set coordinates, set color etc.))
- Some Tool/Program/Utility to render file described above. I want to invoke it from my program, pointing it to file with data. (it's good if this program has a command line API).

But I don't know anything about 3D rendering, so I need your help in suggesting tools (open-source) for render 3D images/videos. Also I don't know anything about input data. So it will be nice if you suggest me render tool + file format to render.

I heard about using Hadoop with `.rib` file format as data to visualize, and `rndr` program to render this data. So I need some analogue.

Please note, my goal is to more deeper learn about Hadoop and distributed computation, not about 3D rendering, so please suggest me simplest solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**KISS: Gnuplot**

If you really only care about using Hadoop, and your only requirement of the rendering is that it takes an input file and makes an image so you can show a completed animation, then I would suggest `gnuplot`. It is actually a graph-drawing program, but it takes scripts and produces image files, and most usefully for you you can enter mathematical formulae to draw rather than constructing 3d worlds to render.

You would simply prepare *n* files which are all the same except for an offset value for the time since start, and gnuplot would produce the appropriate frame.

This is the simplest option, and lets you concentrate on the Hadoop side. To show you how simple, this would produce a frame for an animation of a 3-blade fan spinning:

```
set xrange[-1:1]
set yrange[-1:1]
set polar
unset key
unset border
unset tics
set terminal png size 1000,1000
set output "frame_$FRAME.png" 
plot cos(3*t+$FRAME/5)
```

A great thing about Gnuplot is that you type in commands in an interactive prompt to manipulate the graph, and these are the same commands you put in the script. So once you have something you're happy with, you can either do `save 'newscript.gpt'` or copy out the commands you used. You can recreate the graph by just running `gnuplot newscript.gpt` at a prompt.

Incidentally, it is easier to simulate hard-to-render scenes than to actually construct them, so just put a sleep command in the gnuplot script to make it take 15 seconds or however long.

**The whole banana: Blender**

Blender *is* a 3d rendering system. I believe it is used as a rendering system for some mainstream animations on server farms in exactly the manner you describe. It has quite a learning curve, but I think you should be able to pick up a tutorial or other pre-existing animation project files. From there you would need to work out how to invoke the rendering engine as a command for a specific frame. I've only ever done static rendering in blender, so I can't take you further there. This would be more impressive visually, but no more impressive academically, and you'll waste more time on that side of things.

**My choice**

Personally I would go with gnuplot. You can make 3d plots with the `splot` command rather than the 2d `plot`, and although it's not 3d scene rendering as you might be imagining, it achieves the purpose of making a picture using a script. You can begin with something totally basic like the above until you have your setup going, then introduce more complexity; from an implementation perspective, running a gnuplot script is easier than running a script that also requires a data file, but it's still easy to pre-generate the data and have gnuplot read that when you want to do command + script + data instead of command + script. The key is incrementally increasing the difficulty, not running before you can walk.

If you ultimately find you have spare time at the end and change it to using blender, then that's all free win, and you haven't jeopardised your hadoop project making it pretty.